# kivy widgets : multiple buttons, centering, get window/screen dimensions

Tags: python, kivy

The following App I constructed has a total of 4 widgets, 1 main widget which holds 3 Button widgets. I'm trying to center the buttons on the main widget/screen but the width and height dimensions of the main widget seems to be only 100,100 even though the screen is much larger. So when I try and center a button onto the screen it remains at the bottom left corner. I can change the center_x and center_y of each button by manually setting the co-ords to center the buttons to the window but as soon as I re-size the window the buttons will no longer be centered. Any ideas on how I can get the current screen size and width so the buttons will always be in the correct position, no matter the size of the window? This is what I have so far:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button




class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        start=Widget()

        startbtn=Button(text="Start")
        optionsbtn=Button(text="Options")
        exitbtn=Button(text="Exit")

        start.add_widget(startbtn)
        start.add_widget(optionsbtn)
        start.add_widget(exitbtn)

        startbtn.center=(start.width,start.height)
        optionsbtn.center_x+=200
        optionsbtn.center_y+=100
        exitbtn.center=start.center

        return start

if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

If you test it, you will notice the exit button is not centered but just sitting at the bottom left hand corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `start` widget just has the default size of `100, 100` at the point where you set the center properties of the others. This is normal behaviour, even if it is added to a layout (which doesn't take effect until your function completes). In this case, even that doesn't matter, because the start has had no size set and hasn't been added to anything, so there's no reason its size would be anything else.

In general with kivy you want to work a different way - don't try to set something like the size just once, but *bind* it to that of another widget, then it will be automatically updated. In this case you could do e.g. `start.bind(center=startbtn.setter('center'))`, which is a trick to get a function that sets the startbtn center - and this will be called whenever the `start` center changes.

Even this is overkill here, you would be better off using a layout class, e.g. an anchorlayout, as the top level widget. This will do all the work for you, automatically centering its children. You could pus the 3 other buttons in another layout to give them relative positioning.

This is also made easier by using kv language, which creates bindings automatically from mere property references.

Comment: Yes, it can only center one object, but that object can be a container containing other objects spaced however you like. It's very often useful to nest layouts like this in kivy.